# Comparing two images with pillow

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have two images A and B

[image: A] [image: B]

Both images are of same size(184,184) and I have converted them to mode 'RGB' from 'RGBA'

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageChops
A = Image.open('A.png').convert('RGB')
B = Image.open('B.png').convert('RGB')

flip = A.transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
diff = ImageChops.difference(flip,B)

# Expected
diff.getbbox() is None

# output
diff.getbbox() == (28,28,156,156)
```

How do I compare two shapes in pillow

Comment: why do you expect it to be None? what does the difference look like?

Comment: I expect it to be None because visually if you see, when you flip the image they will be the same.

Comment: display the difference image.